# Doctrine: Not possible to addWhere with between columnA and columnB

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com

With this hint it works perfect, but now I have another question(s)

I would like to set a 'andWhere' clausel, with the following statement: `AND 351 between columnA and columnB`

I tried it with the following PHP Code:

```
$rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAlias()[0];
$queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf(:value between columnA and columnB ));
$queryBuilder->setParameter('value', '351');
But if I try this, I get the following error from doctrine:

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 52: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'between'
```

It seems that it's not possible to add this where clause. Is there another option to add this where?

Answer (score 0):

Between should be used like this :

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf(%s.columnA between :value1 and :value2), $queryBuilder->getRootAlias()[0]);
```

If you want to test that the value 351 is in columnA and columnB you should do an IN if it's an collection of ID.